# Can't generate ROC-AUC curve from Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to predict ethnicity using features derived from certain variables. From my previous question [How to interpret this triangular shape ROC AUC curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208897/how-to-interpret-this-triangular-shape-roc-auc-curve), I have learned to use decision_function or predict_proba instead of actual predictions to fit the ROC curve.

I am able to generate ROC-AUC graph using the following codes, with the SVM classifier

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import nltk
import re
import random
from random import randint
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as sk_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# multi_class : str, {'ovr', 'multinomial'}
#$$
lr = LogisticRegression()
#lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', class_weight='auto', solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial')
nb = MultinomialNB(fit_prior=False)
#$$
svm = LinearSVC(class_weight='auto')

dv = DictVectorizer()

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("FamilySearchData_All_OCT2015_newEthnicity_filledEthnicity_processedName_trimmedCol.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8")
df = DataFrame(data)

# Class list
ethnicity2 = ['fr', 'en', 'ir', 'sc', 'others', 'ab', 'rus', 'ch', 'it', 'ja']
Ab_group = ['fr', 'en', 'ir', 'sc', 'others', 'ab', 'rus', 'ch', 'it', 'ja', 'fn', 'metis', 'inuit']
Ab_lang = ['fr', 'en', 'ir', 'sc', 'others', 'ab', 'rus', 'ch', 'it', 'ja', 'x', 'y']

############################################
########## CONTROL ROOM ####################
# change-tag: '#$$'
# Output file name decoration
# Total N = 5031794
#$$
featureUsed = 8
#$$
subsample_size = 50000
#$$
ethnicity_var = 'ethnicity2' # Ab_group, Ab_tribe, Ab_lang
count = 0

# Declaration
print 'No. features=', featureUsed
print 'N=', subsample_size, 'Training_N=', subsample_size/2, 'Test_N=', subsample_size/2
print 'ethnicity_var:', ethnicity_var
#$$
print ethnicity2
#$$
print 'ML classifier:', 'svm = LinearSVC(class_weight=\'auto\')'
print ''
print '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////'
print ''

try:
    #$$
    for i in ethnicity2:
        count+=1
        ethnicity_tar = str(i) # fr, en, ir, sc, others, ab, rus, ch, it, ja
        # fn, metis, inuit; algonquian, iroquoian, athapaskan, wakashan, siouan, salish, tsimshian, kootenay
        ############################################
        ############################################

        def ethnicity_target(row):
            try:
                if row[ethnicity_var] == ethnicity_tar:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 0
            except: return None
        df['ethnicity_scan'] = df.apply(ethnicity_target, axis=1)
        print '1=', ethnicity_tar
        print '0=', 'non-'+ethnicity_tar

        # Random sampling a smaller dataframe for debugging
        rows = random.sample(df.index, subsample_size)
        df = df.ix[rows] # Warning!!!! overwriting original df
        print 'Class count:'
        print df['ethnicity_scan'].value_counts()

        # Assign X and y variables
        X = df.raw_name.values
        y = df.ethnicity_scan.values

        # Feature extraction functions
        def feature_full_name(nameString):
            #... codes omitted

        # Transform format of X variables, and spit out a numpy array for all features
        my_dict = [{'last-name': feature_full_last_name(i)} for i in X]
        my_dict2 = [list_to_dict(feature_twoLetters(feature_full_last_name(i))) for i in X]
        my_dict3 = [list_to_dict(feature_threeLetters(feature_full_last_name(i))) for i in X]
        my_dict4 = [list_to_dict(feature_fourLetters(feature_full_last_name(i))) for i in X]

        my_dict5 = [{'first-name': feature_full_first_name(i)} for i in X]
        my_dict6 = [list_to_dict(feature_twoLetters(feature_full_first_name(i))) for i in X]
        my_dict7 = [list_to_dict(feature_threeLetters(feature_full_first_name(i))) for i in X]
        my_dict8 = [list_to_dict(feature_fourLetters(feature_full_first_name(i))) for i in X]

        all_dict = []
        for i in range(0, len(my_dict)):
            temp_dict = dict(my_dict[i].items() + my_dict2[i].items() + my_dict3[i].items() + my_dict4[i].items()
                + my_dict5[i].items() + my_dict6[i].items() + my_dict7[i].items() + my_dict8[i].items())
            all_dict.append(temp_dict)

        newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict)

        # Separate the training and testing data sets
        half_cut = int(len(df)/2.0)*-1
        X_train = newX[:half_cut]
        X_test = newX[half_cut:]
        y_train = y[:half_cut]
        y_test = y[half_cut:]

        # Fitting X and y into model, using training data
        #$$
        svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

        # Making predictions using trained data
        #$$
        y_train_predictions = svm.predict(X_train)
        #$$
        y_test_predictions = svm.predict(X_test)

        #print (y_train_predictions == y_train).sum().astype(float)/(y_train.shape[0])
        print 'Accuracy:',(y_test_predictions == y_test).sum().astype(float)/(y_test.shape[0])

        print 'Classification report:'
        print classification_report(y_test, y_test_predictions)
        #print sk_confusion_matrix(y_train, y_train_predictions)
        print 'Confusion matrix:'
        print sk_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_predictions)

        #print y_test[1:20]
        #print y_test_predictions[1:20]

        #print y_test[1:10]
        #print np.bincount(y_test)
        #print np.bincount(y_test_predictions)

        # Find and plot AUC
        false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_predictions)
        roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)

        # Find and plot AUC
        y_score = svm.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
        false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
        roc_auc = auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
        print 'AUC-'+ethnicity_tar+'=',roc_auc

        # Get different color each graph line
        colorSet = ['navy', 'greenyellow', 'deepskyblue', 'darkviolet', 'crimson', 
            'darkslategray', 'indigo', 'brown', 'orange', 'palevioletred', 'mediumseagreen',
            'k', 'darkgoldenrod', 'g', 'midnightblue', 'c', 'y', 'r', 'b', 'm', 'lawngreen'
            'mediumturquoise', 'lime', 'teal', 'drive', 'sienna', 'sandybrown']
        color = colorSet[count-1]

        # Plotting
        plt.title('ROC')
        plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, c=color, label=('AUC-'+ethnicity_tar+'= %0.2f'%roc_auc))
        plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size':8})
        plt.plot([0,1],[0,1], color='lightgrey', linestyle='--')
        plt.xlim([-0.05,1.0])
        plt.ylim([0.0,1.05])
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
        #plt.show()
        # Save ROC graphs
        plt.savefig('TESTROCXXX.jpg')

        print ''
        print '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////'
        print ''
except Exception as e:
    print 'Error:', str(e)
    print ''
    print '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////'
    print ''
```

Which gives:

[image]

But when I try to use Naive Bayes classifier, I made the following changes:

```
nb.fit(X_train, y_train) # from svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train_predictions = nb.predict(X_train) # from y_train_predictions = svm.predict(X_train)

y_test_predictions = nb.predict(X_test) # from y_test_predictions = svm.predict(X_test)

y_score = nb.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test) # from y_score = svm.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
Error: bad input shape (25000L, 2L)
```

Edited: After adding [:,1] as suggested, I have shown 4 ROC graphs, the last two are NB, which look strange.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: At which line exactly this error occurs? What shape X_test and X_train has? Also, why do you call fit on nb (and svm) second time? You already have trained model at that data. You can just call nb.predict_proba(X_test) at last line.

Comment: You're importing nltk in your example. Is this still necessary?

Comment: @Olologin The error happens after the predict_proba statement, specifically at 'false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)'. The X_test and X_train are sparse matrix with shape (25000, 63470)

Comment: @colidyre No it is not necessary, but it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to mention in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33218642/1030820 answer that you need to choose some column (from possible two) in case when you are using predict_proba results for roc_curve.

```
false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score[:,1])
```

This may work.

**Added:** Well, it's Naive Bayes, in most cases it should not beat LR. It's more simpler model than LR and can't catch interactions between features (That's why it's called Naive, by the way). In ML papers authors often use NB just to make some starting point in accuracy, show result of simplest ML algorithm, and compare more advanced algos to it.

Look also here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#naive-bayes

> On the flip side, although naive Bayes is known as a decent
>   classifier, it is known to be a bad estimator, so the probability
>   outputs from predict_proba are not to be taken too seriously.

Comment: I have added it (please see my edits above). It does generate ROC graph and AUC, but it looks strange (somewhat like my previous question).

Comment: So it is likely not due to my possible mistake in coding despite the strange looking graph for NB? Me making mistake somewhere I am not aware of is what I am worrying.

Comment: Also for another question, the 'fr' always get really high RUC despite I am deliberately using very low training data 1k (50:50 training/test). Is it expected? ('fr' is one of the highest prevalence class consists of about 1/3 of total data)

Comment: I didn't check your code, but graphs look ok. Are you training classifiers as OneVsAll? i.e you train each classifier to distinguish between his classes and any others?

Comment: pred_proba[:,1]  is the key.  If you pass pred_proba without selecting the 1st column you will get an error that your passing a 2 dimensional array into a 1 dimensional parameter